# Access an Activity from a Fragment plugged into another Activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, fragment

I have been using [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) as a base for my project.

I have changed the project to use an ArrayAdapter for the titles-fragment's ListItems and changed the DetailsFragment's View to display a custom layout, which as a Button that is supposed to add an entry into a database.

Instead of generating widgets like in the example, I just inflate a custom XML into the FrameLayout besides the TitlesFragment in the 'layout-land' version of the layout.

My problem stems from the fact that DetailsFragment is plugged into the MainActivity when in Landscape mode but gets it's own DetailsActivty if it is in Portrait mode.

The Button I have in my custom layout for the details-fragment calls a function in its onClick() that is called AddNewItem.

So when the Button was clicked in Landscape mode, it crashed, because there was no AddNewItem in the MainActivity. I solved this by using a BroadcastReceiver, so when the button is clicked, a method named AddNewItem in MainActivity.java instead broadcasts a custom event and i have a BroadcastReceiver that calls the AddNewItem in DetailsFragment.java.

It looks like this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DetailsActivity  m = (DetailsActivity) DetailsActivity.getActivityInstance(); // see below for what getActivityInstance does

        LayoutInflater mInf = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View myView = mInf.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);

        ((DetailsActivity) m).AddNewItem(myView);
    }
}
```

But this gives me:

08-11 13:37:50.687: E/AndroidRuntime(6766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver in.falkeninc.umt_v0_9_8_1.MyReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException

I am not sure what is happening. Because I am also using a static variable in DetailsActivity.java to be able to reach it inside the BroadcastReceiver. The code looks like this:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    ...
    public static SherlockFragmentActivity activityInstance;
    ...
    activityInstance = this;   // in the onCreate
    ...
    public static SherlockFragmentActivity getActivityInstance(){
       return activityInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem stems from the fact that DetailsFragment is plugged into
>   the MainActivity when in Landscape mode but gets it's own
>   DetailsActivty if it is in Portrait mode.

This shouldn't be a problem. Although you have two activities you have the same `DetailsFragment` class in both of them. If a `Button` from that fragment is doing something then you should keep it at that fragment's level(that would be an ideal fragment, one that is self contained, a fragment that doesn't know or care where is put). If you do require the activity for the work in that method, you should add extra details.

Also, if the behavior is common to both activities you could make a base activity holding that method and let the two current activities inherit from that, so it will be available to the fragment no matter what.

> public static SherlockFragmentActivity activityInstance;

Don't keep static references to activities, you risk leaking them.
Also, don't access activities from outside their own context. When an activity is not the one interacting with the user(it's `onPause()` has been called) that activity could as well be completely destroyed and trying to access it in another activity could bring you lots of problems.

Comment: You are probably right; because the 'm' variable is null so getActivityInstance() doesnt do the trick after all. 

And also as you hint at, the behaviours will not exactly the same every time. I might have to duplicate some code here. 
The method that adds the new item is huge and i might have gone out of my way to avoid duplication. Many people seems to say that programming for both tablet and phone makes it unavoidable. :/

Comment: @CupOfQuestions Coding for phone and tablet layouts shouldn't be that problematic if the pieces aka the fragments are well built. Also, with a base class you might get away without the need of duplicating ode. Also, that **huge** method doesn't sound to good:)

Comment: Haha the method isn't *that* big, just very tedious to maintain :) Anyway, I solved this by making a new class like this, like you said:

    class BaseDBActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    ...
    public void addNewItem() {
    ... // huge tedious code that gets data from 10 widgets
    }

Then both MainActivity and DetailsActivity extends this, there is now a addNewItem in both and they work :) 

Thanks :)

Comment: Just for people looking at this later (since the thread keeps getting votes), I went away from the Broadcast methods / "Base" classes apprach and implemented onClick listeners on the buttons in the DialogFragment instead. So no android:onClick was used after all. (Since they only can call a method inside their own activity). (@Luksprog, i would upvote you but i can't yet!)